# Getting an error while updating a filed using another field in MongoDB 4.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**The Query Script**

```
db.getCollection('users').updateMany({'full_name':{$exists:false}},
    [
        {"$set": {"full_name": { "$concat": ["$name", " "] }}}
    ]         
)
```

**Getting This Error**

```
Failed to execute script.

Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators 
Details:
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: where you executing  this query? and what is the version of mongodb?
it requires mongodb v4.2 or above and this will not work if you are using robo mongo or 3t because of old shell version, if you are executing this in mongo shell this will work, if its not work then you have to update mongo shell version.

Comment: db version v4.2.6 & Robo 3T 1.3.1